# Inserting into a list - error " 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Tags: python, list

Can I get help with figuring out what I am doing wrong here? I have a list of lists and need to insert a string into a particular index of a particular list. For instance, in this example list:

```
List = [['a', 1, 'letter'], ['b', 2], ['zero', 3, 'number']]
```

I want to insert 'letter' into the second list, after the number 2, so that List will appear:

```
List = [['a', 1, 'letter'], ['b', 2, 'letter'], ['zero', 3, 'number']]
```

I have tried the following:

```
List = [['a', 1, 'letter'], ['b', 2], ['zero', 3, 'number']]
for i in len(List):
    List.insert([1][2], 'letter')
print(List)
```

In the complicated program I am working on, I am receiving this error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using a `for` loop if you only want to append to the second list?

You can simply do `List[1].append('letter')`.

By the way, are you sure this is the actual code you are running? You should be getting another error (`TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the subscript operator (`[]`) to access the inner list, and then call `insert` on it:

```
>>> lst = [['a', 1, 'letter'], ['b', 2], ['zero', 3, 'number']]
>>> lst[1].insert(2, 'letter')
>>> lst
[['a', 1, 'letter'], ['b', 2, 'letter'], ['zero', 3, 'number']]
```